# Calling name method on current_user causes testing error (ruby on rails)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, railstutorial.org

I finished up to chapter 11 in Michael Hartl's Rails tutorial, and afterwards I started looking for a way to use the [thumbs_up gem](https://github.com/bouchard/thumbs_up) to add some reputation and voting functions to the microposts.

I want to display the current user's reputation in a small box (like Stack Overflow) in the navbar. I can get the user name and reputation to display fine using:

```
       <li class="rep_box"><%= current_user.name %> <%= current_user.karma %> </li>
```

The page is working fine and renders the user's name and reputation correctly, but now I'm getting several errors and fails. If I remove the above line of code, everything works correctly again.

Here is an example of the errors -- they are all pretty much the same:

```
>ERROR["test_should_get_home", StaticPagesControllerTest, 2016-04-09 04:36:31 -0400]
 test_should_get_home#StaticPagesControllerTest (1460190991.59s)
ActionView::Template::Error:         ActionView::Template::Error: undefined method `name' for nil:NilClass
            app/views/layouts/_header.erb:6:in `_app_views_layouts__header_erb__1475229759153232172_2241208160'
            app/views/layouts/application.html.erb:12:in `_app_views_layouts_application_html_erb__4357373253304461109_2216429940'
            test/controllers/static_pages_controller_test.rb:9:in `block in <class:StaticPagesControllerTest>'
        app/views/layouts/_header.erb:6:in `_app_views_layouts__header_erb__1475229759153232172_2241208160'
        app/views/layouts/application.html.erb:12:in `_app_views_layouts_application_html_erb__4357373253304461109_2216429940'
        test/controllers/static_pages_controller_test.rb:9:in `block in <class:StaticPagesControllerTest>'
```

Comment: Can anybody verify if this can be fixed by adding something to the test_helper.rb's log_in_as() function?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
undefined method `name' for nil:NilClass
```

This means that `current_user` is `nil` when `name` is called on it. Make sure that it's assigned properly at that point and that error will go away.

Comment: I called .nil? on current_user.name and it came back false.

Comment: It's the tests that are failing.

Comment: @gbutters, try putting your nil check right in with the view, so you know it's in the right context, e.g. `<%= puts "cun?: #{current_user.nil?}"; current_user.name %>`

Comment: I tried this out, but I'm not sure to what end. It printed out a bunch of extra information in the tests like "cun?: false, cun?: true ..."

Comment: @gbutters, whenever it prints out `cun?: true`, that means `current_user` is `nil` and you'll get that undefined method error. So you need to find out why  `current_user` doesn't get set properly in that case.

Answer (score 1):

You need to `sign_in` a user before there is a `current_user`.

You could do something like:

```
let(:curr_user) { User.create(...attrs...) }
sign_in curr_user
```

From the [Devise documentation](https://github.com/plataformatec/devise):

> Devise includes some test helpers for functional specs. In order to
>   use them, you need to include Devise in your functional tests by
>   adding the following to the bottom of your test/test_helper.rb file
>   (make sure you place it out of scope of ActiveSupport::TestCase which
>   is the default class inside of test/test_helper.rb):
>
> ```
> class ActionController::TestCase   
>    include Devise::TestHelpers 
> end
> ```
>
> Just be sure that this inclusion is made after the require
>   'rspec/rails' directive.
>
> Now you are ready to use the sign_in and sign_out methods. Such
>   methods have the same signature as in controllers:
>
> ```
> sign_in :user, @user   # sign_in(scope, resource) 
> sign_in @user          # sign_in(resource)
>
> sign_out :user         # sign_out(scope) 
> sign_out @user         # sign_out(resource)
> ```

Otherwise, `current_user` is, correctly, going to be `nil`. If you want your code to tolerate this, then you should guard that bit in the view with something like `unless current_user.nil?`. I have also seen something someone create a `current_user_or_guest` method that replaces their usage of `current_user`.

In a helper, they created something like this:

```
  def current_or_guest_user
    if current_user
      current_user
    else
      User.new
    end
  end
```

**EDIT:**

In [Michael Hartl's Rails tutorial](https://www.railstutorial.org/book/log_in_log_out), it does not use Devise and has you create a `current_user` method which looks like this:

```
def current_user
  User.find_by(id: session[:user_id])
end
```

When there is no `session[:user_id]`, this `current_user` method will return `nil`. You will still need to authenticate a user before `current_user` will no longer return `nil`. There is already test code that does user authentication testing in `test/integration/users_login_test.rb`.

So, in your tests you will need to ensure that something like `log_in User.find_by(id: <some valid ID>)` is executed to authenticate a user. This will ensure that `current_user` executes as it would in a normal usage context.

You could add a `test/support` directory and inside of that create `login_helpers.rb` with this:

```
def log_in_with(email,password) do
  get login_path
  post login_path, session: { email: email, password: password }
end
```

Then, to ensure that these methods are available, inside your `test/test_helper.rb` add:

```
Dir[Rails.root.join('test/support/**/*.rb')].each { |f| require f }
```

Now, in your tests which require an authenticated user, do:

```
log_in_with('a_valid_email', 'its valid password')
```

Comment: There is a bit on testing in the thumbs_up documentation: https://github.com/bouchard/thumbs_up wonder if that would do it?

Comment: Then what are you using that creates the `current_user` method? That isn't created by ThumbsUp.

Comment: That bit on testing is for testing ThumbsUp, not testing your app's implementation of ThumbsUp. What you are doing is correct, you are just missing something that establishes the current user.

Comment: I found more details in that Rails tutorial and have edited my answer. I will add more code in a couple minutes.

Comment: Could this id be declared in the users.yml fixtures file under a model user?

Comment: No. This would not go in the YAML file.

Comment: There seems to be a similar function in the test_helper.rb 'log_in_as'  (which logs in a test user). Can you check out the tutorial and see if something can be added to the test_helper to fix this?